# How to properly deploy a nuxt app on firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have created a Nuxt.js SSR App and deployed it on firebase with the following cloud function:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

const { Nuxt } = require("nuxt-start");
const nuxtConfig = require("./nuxt.config.js");

const config = {
    ...nuxtConfig,
    dev: false,
    debug: false,
    buildDir: "nuxt"
};

const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

exports.ssrapp = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    await nuxt.ready();
    nuxt.render(req, res);
});
```

However, I am not really satisfied with this solution. The cold start of the cloud function results in a terrible initial page load of the app of 5-10 seconds.

Is there a better way to deploy the App and avoid those long initial page loads?

Comment: You'll be able to use Nuxt with serverless functions soon, this will help substantially on cold start.

Comment: @kissu Is there any more information on this yet? So there is actually no other way to deploy a firebase app?

Comment: This is pretty much how firebase is working. Maybe you can optimize somehow but the result will still be around the same. Do you really need a server here or could `target: 'static'` be enough? As for Nuxt3, I check Nuxtnation on 15/16th September.